# How can I share Request Types between multple projects in Jira Service Desk?

Tags: jira

I learned that this option is not available.
[The request](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JSDSERVER-4763) is still as a 'suggestion' in the Atlassian's Jira.

Anyone knows any way to do this but manually copying the information and form fields for every request type, and for every project, every time?